# android mediaplayer.create returns null

Tags: android

I'm trying to play sound from URI Using MediaPlayer Class but when i tried this my app crashed then i noticed that mediaplayer.create() function returns null what can i do to solve this problem?`

```
mediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse("http://example.com/files/music.mp3"));
if (mediaplayer==null){
    Toast.makeText(this,"media player is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
else
    mediaplayer.start();
```

now when i run my app it shows Toast message "media player is null"

Comment: Read the logcat to see why the creation failed

Comment: yes .. I looked in the logcat and it said that internet permission is required even though i already add it .my error was that i add the permission in the wrong place in the manifest file.  i added it inside the application tag where I must add it outside. thank you the problem solved. @cricket_007

Comment: did you use`private  MediaPlayer mp  = new MediaPlayer();` otherwise it will return null

Answer (score 2):

I experienced similar problem with MediaPlayer

the create() method sometimes return null

Some of the file types I have tried are mp3, wav, and m4a

I know they aren't corrupt because I can play them in winamp/itunes

While the documentation does say that it supports those file type, it turns out that it actually doesn't

I noticed that when the audio file (regardless of file type) is 10Mb or more then the MediaPlayer will return null. It made me conclude that MediaPlayer can't play file above certain bitrates. big size = better quality.

So my solution is: Convert everything into .mp3 with 128kbps bitrate

EDIT:
It looks like the problem is with my emulator, when I used a real Android device, everything works perfectly. Make sure that you test on real Android Device. Or in my case, I created another AVD profile with better spec and it works

Comment: This comment for developers, who will be looking for answers in the future.



@grandia you are right about the file format, more about supported formats here(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats). I also recommend you check the audio file name. In my case MediaPlayer returns null because of the wrong file name:



12-24-05 13:45:34.mp3 <- prevent naming like this with spaces and different symbols.
12_24_05_13_45_35.mp3 <- looks not better, but you should try to simplify or refactor your file name



In my example above, I using the date as a file name.